# Is it possible to set an order of preferred loudspeakers that dynamically change without writing scripts?

Tags: pulseaudio, multi-monitor

I have a laptop that has its own soundspeakers. Then I have a monitor (DP through USB-C, stereo 2.0) that has better soundspeakers that I prefer to use when connected. I also have a portable soundspeaker (bluetooth, 3.5 jack and micro-usb connection, stereo) I use when watching/listening videos while cooking . I also sometimes plug my laptop to my home cinema via HDMI to an AVR (5.1). All these dynamically change and it can happen three or four are connected at the same time.

I would like to set a priority of the devices like this:

1. AVR
2. Portable soundspeaker
3. Monitor
4. Laptop

so that they would be magically autoselected when I change the configuratino (whcih can happen several times a day)

Right now, PulseAudio tries to pick the best one and sometimes it suceeds, sometimes not.

1. If my Googling is correct, there is no way I could set the default via a config file or some GUI and I need to write a script. I am a bit surprised by it - I think this must be a common use case. So I am asking if my research has been wrong before I try to write such a script (or in case somebody has such a script, feel free to share it, the only thing I found is this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/263248/set-hdmi-sound-output-automatically-on-connect-disconnect - and that is not as complex as my setup)
2. Another thing that puzzles me is that in all the tools in Gnome, KDE or in pactl, the actual names of the devices like "DELL U4320Q", "JieLi AC46" etc. are burried (in pactl under card>properties>device.product.name) and not exposed in the UI. Why is that? They would be definitely more human readable. For the monitor, I generally get something like "dmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort" - how am I supposed to know which port did I connect the monitor to (and which port is 0 and which is 1)? Is there any reason why this is like this? Every time I update my install, I am curious if anything has changed for the better, but it largely stays the same. Would Pipewire help with this? I thought PulseAudio was supposed to make this kind of usage simple:-).

Comment: I do not think this is possible and I reported it here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/issues/1978#note_1209210 (I switched to Pipewire in the meantime, it behaves the same as Pulse Audio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end I wrote the following script `/usr/local/bin/hdmi_sound_toggle.py` that automates the switching for me. It uses the script provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24933353/1269040 to find out which monitors are connected.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
# find_monitors is the script from the internet to check EDID data - I put it into $PATH
# the following implements "find_monitors 2>/dev/null | grep '#' 2>/dev/null 1"
# my internal monitor is confusing the script, outputing some weird binary data, so I strip it on the second line
monitors_gibberish = subprocess.check_output(("find_monitors"), shell=True,  stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
monitors_one_line = monitors_gibberish.replace(b'# eDP-1-1 HDMI   \xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\r\xae\x0c\x15', b'').decode("UTF-8")
monitors_lines = [i for i in monitors_one_line.split('\n') if i]
default_sink = ''
alsa_card = "pci-0000_01_00.1"
port_number = 0
profile_name = ''
if "H/K AV AMP" in monitors_one_line:
    # AVR is connected through HDMI port and that has always number three, so it has "-extra2" added the profile name
    profile_name = "hdmi-surround-extra2"
elif "DELL U4320Q" in monitors_one_line:
    for i in monitors_lines:
        if "DELL U4320Q" in i:
            # This is being split: '# DP-0 DisplayPort   DELL U4320Q'
            # DP numbering start at 0, HDMI numbering in Pipewire/alsa starts at 1
            port_number = int(i.split(" ")[1].split("-")[1]) + 1
            if port_number == 1:
                profile_name = "hdmi-stereo"
            elif port_number == 2:
                profile_name = "hdmi-stereo-extra1"
# first we need to set default profile for HDMI - it tells Pipewire to which device it should send audio streams over HDMI
if profile_name:
    default_sink = 'alsa_output.' + alsa_card + "." + profile_name
    subprocess.run(["pactl", "set-card-profile", "alsa_card." + alsa_card, "output:" + profile_name])
    # and now we switch the default sink, ie. device that should play all audio by default
    subprocess.run(["pactl", "set-default-sink", default_sink])
~
```

To run it automatically, I put this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="drm", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/run_hdmi_sound_toggle"
```

to `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-hdmi_sound.rules`  and ran `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules`. `/usr/local/bin/run_hdmi_sound_toggle` is jsut a wrapper script that deals with udev running under root and failing to connect to user-run Pipewire/PulseAudio:

```
#!/bin/bash
systemctl --machine=drew@.host --user --now start hdmi_sound_toggle.service
```

And the appropriate systemd service file in `~/.config/systemd/user/hdmi_sound_toggle.service` is:

```
[Unit]
Description=Runs /usr/local/bin/hdmi_sound_toggle.py to switch to the correct sound output
  
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/hdmi_sound_toggle.py
```

Then it runs on DHMI/USB-C/DP plug/unplug.

It only does its thing with devices connected over DP or HDMI - Pipewire seems to be handling the USB/Bluetooth devices just fine.